# proof of vanishing theorem of Abelian variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties

Sorry for my bad English.

In Mumford's "Abelian variety" section 16, there is vanishing theorem as follow;

> Let $X$ be an abelian variety of dimension $g$, and $L$ be an ample line bundle. Then there is a unique integer $i=i(L), 0\leq i\leq g$, such that $H^p(X, L)=0 $ for $p\neq i$, and $H^i(X,L)\neq 0$.

The last of the proof  is as follow;

> if  $h^i(L):=\dim_k H^i(X, L)$, we have $\Sigma_{i=0}^q h^i(L)h^{q-i}(L^{-1})= 0, (0\le q< g),$ and $\Sigma_{i=0}^g h^i(L)h^{g-i}(L^{-1})=\deg \phi_L$.
> Now  $h^i(L)\ge 0$ so we get this proposition.

But I can't understand why this  equation deduce this proposition. In fact, for example $g=1, h^0(L)>0, h^1(L)>0, h^0(L^{-1})=0, h^1(L^{-1})>0$ is counterexample.

Please help me, thanks.

Comment: For $g=1$ can you find an ample $L$ with $h^1(L)>0$?

Comment: By Riemann-Roch Theorem and Kodaira vanishing theorem, in fact we get $i(L)=0$  so I can't find it. But is it trivial (without Kodaira vanishing theorem)? And we get similarly  counterexample for all $g>0$, $h^0(L)>0, h^0(L^{-1})>0, h^g(L)=0, h^g(L^{-1})=0$.

Comment: Mumford claims that $\sum_{i=0}^qh^i(L)h^{q-i}(L^{-1})=0$ for $q\neq g$ (including $q>g$).

Comment: If $h^0(L^{-1})\neq 0$, same is true for any positive powers. Then, since $L^n$ is an effective divisor, its inverse can not have a section.